# Wait until glutPostRedisplay() refreshes

Tags: opengl, glut

Is there some kind of synchronization primitive that allows us to block a thread until an OpenGL display has refreshed, i.e. after a call to `glutPostRedisplay()`?

```
static GLubyte *pixels = NULL;
glutSetWindow(mainWindow);
glutPostRedisplay();
pixels = (GLubyte *)realloc(pixels, format_nchannels * sizeof(GLubyte) * width * height);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, FORMAT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

I'm trying to copy over the pixels from the GPU to memory after refreshing the drawing. However, I'm finding that after `glReadPixels` executes, pixels does not necessarily contain the updated image.

Comment: Unless you are using multiple threads and contexts, what you've described should not be possible. `glReadPixels (...)` causes an implicit `glFinish (...)` and will not return until all commands before it have finished.

Answer (score 2):

glutPostRedisplay does not refresh anything. It just sets a flag and that's it. The flag set by glutPostRedisplay is tested for in the main loop, and if there are not further events to be processed and the flag is set, the main loop calls the display function. If you were waiting for the display to finish after calling glutPostRedisplay but before returning to the main loop your program will wait indefinitely, never returning to the main loop and thus giving it a chance to redisplay.

If you want to take a screenshot, just introduce another flag yourself and process it in the display function.

For robustness reasons you should not `glReadPixels` from the main framebuffer (its contents may be undefined, by being obscured by a window), but when a screenshot is requested render to a FBO, from which you can save the screenshot and blit it to the main framebuffer.